# How to completely collapse a SearchView after an item selected?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I've been struggling with this for weeks.. I have a global search that offers up a custom listview with suggestions as a user types. When a user selects an option, I want the searchview to return to its completely collapsed state.

[image]

Instead, it shrinks down but stays in a slightly expanded view.

[image]

I've thrown EVERYTHING I can find at this thing to close it, but cannot for the life of me get the right method. Here's the function:

```
    final SearchView.OnCloseListener closeListener = new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            return closeSearch();
        }
    };

    protected boolean closeSearch() {
    _searchView.clearFocus();
    _searchView.setQuery("", false);
    _searchView.setFocusable(false);
    _searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
    isSearchFragmentVisible(false);
    return false;
}
```

Close search is then manually called when an item is selected from the custom "suggestion" listview.

Comment: searchMenuItem.collapseActionView(); Thanks To [Newinjava](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928253/how-to-dismiss-close-collapse-searchview-in-actionbar-in-mainactivity?rq=1)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Found it. The call should be `_searchView.onActionViewCollapsed()`. Why on earth you call a "listener" style method (ie, one that begins with 'on') is beyond me.

Comment: I agree with Sebastian : using a searchView from android.support.v7.widget.SearchView in a menuItem from android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat in an ActionBar, the searchView cannot be collapsed calling 

`MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenuItem);`

I had to call 

`searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();` 

in the "onQueryTextSubmit" callback.

The keybaord is dismissed too.

My keyboard "Ok" button label switches between "Ok" and "Next" between successive invocation of the searchView. I don't know why actually.

Comment: only @Ender Muab'Dib 's answer worked for me, you should call menuSearch.collapseActionView()

Answer (score 54):

Instead of calling `_searchView.onActionViewCollapsed()` call `menuItem.collapseActionView()` where `_searchView = menuItem.getActionView()`.

Comment: It works for API level 14 and above.  If using the compat library, you can use MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(menuItem);

Comment: I am using this method to close the searchview and keyboard. But the thing is then when I reopen it for another search, I can not submit the query because on the keyboard the 'Go' button is changed into a 'Next' button. Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: In my case .collapseActionView() using android support v7 widget SearchView doesn't work. Instead calling onActionViewCollapred() work as exprected..

Comment: Perfect! Visually it is way better than the alternative. Plus the menuItem object is often visible from within the caller, which the searchView usually isn't (I am basing these statements on the code that is usually around).

Answer (score 21):

@sebastian that's not actually right.

I've been stucked at this issue for a while, but finally I've managed to handle it in the right way. You're suppose to call ***menuSearch.collapseActionView();*** instead. This method will call *onActionViewCollapsed*, which you could override. So you don't call a listener ;)

```
MenuItem menuSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.itemSearch);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuSearch.getActionView();
//Don't use next line
//searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
menuSearch.collapseActionView();
```

Answer (score 13):

If you're using **Toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)** and the corresponding **SearchView (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView)** with it, this works:

```
    searchView.setQuery("", false);
    searchView.clearFocus();
    searchView.setIconified(true);
```

Comment: Only this worked for me, using AppCompat with Toolbar and support SearchView. Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 8):

You should clear the search, remove the focus and then call:

```
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
searchView.setIconified(true); // Call this twice
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

It works for me.

Comment: This is because, first call will clear the text and the second call closes the searchview. See the implementation here: http://blog.http417.com/2014/07/how-to-close-searchview-programatically.html or https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/jb-mr2-release/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java (search for setIconified method) `public void setIconified(boolean iconify) {
        if (iconify) {
            onCloseClicked();
        } else {
            onSearchClicked();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me and it also closed the keyboard by Default

```
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(menuItem);
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me `searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();`

Answer (score 2):

Returning `false` should have been sufficient based on the latest [documentation](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/469286122bcbbecbdd0bef74fb50f9d8920e77b9/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#L234) and the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/469286122bcbbecbdd0bef74fb50f9d8920e77b9/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#L1151) **iff** `iconifiedByDefault == true`.

Did you by any chance define `iconifiedByDefault="false"` or called `setIconifiedByDefault(false)`?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the 'Go' button to 'Next', so the only method that worked for me (on API 19) is typing
    `closeBtn.performClick();`
    `closeBtn.performClick();`
(Clicking 'close' button twice) in the `OnEditorActionListener` of the `AutoCompleteTextView`.
You can get the `AutoCompleteTextView` like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout1.getChildAt(2);
LinearLayout linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.getChildAt(1);
AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) linearLayout3.getChildAt(0);
```