# How to dismiss/close/collapse SearchView in ActionBar in MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I'm trying to clear and close SearchView after entering a value. I found a solution but it closes the search and won't perform any action if I try to search again.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchListener);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

SearchView.OnQueryTextListener searchListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        new JsoupGetData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q="+ query + "&lang=pl").execute();
        try {
            searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

I can search only for the first time. Every next time it only closes my input keyboard and does nothing. How can it be performed in a right way?

Edit.
Suggested change looks like this:

```
        try {
            searchView.setIconified(true);
        }
```

activity_main_actions.xml:

```
   <!-- Search Widget -->
   <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
       android:title="@string/action_search"
       android:showAsAction="always"
       android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Edit2:

I changed `showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"` but it closes my app when I click the search.

I also put the listener inside OnCreateOptionsMenu to see if it changes anything:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search); 
    searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if (searchMenuItem != null) {
                    boolean closed = searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "closing: " + closed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                new JsoupGetData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q="+ query + "&lang=pl").execute();
                return false;
            }
    });    
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And the `closed` boolean is `false` - I don't know why. I read [the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#collapseActionView()) but it tells me nothing.

Edit3:

I've read too much Internet on this subject and it is not clear for me yet. Search widget is cleared, keyboard is hidden and action is performed. The only issue is the search isn't collapsed so it covers the rest of action buttons on the ActionBar.

```
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                searchView.clearFocus();
                new JsoupGetData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q="+ query + "&lang=pl").execute();
                return false;
            }
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23123777/2194222) I read that collapseActionView() will not work, because my Search is not a view but a widget.

Comment: Why aren't you using setIconified() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setIconified%28boolean%29 ? You shouldn't call onActionViewCollapsed().

Comment: @Luksprog it works only in part. It erases typed query and performs the action but input keyboard is not hidden and search field is not closed.

Comment: How exactly do you search again? Nothing happens? I've checked both onActionViewCollapsed() and setIconfied() and both clear the text, close the SearchView and remove the keyboard. Next searches are ok.

Comment: Next search works ok - there was Internet connection problem. setIconified() clears the field but focus isn't lost and cursos is blinking in the search field and keyboard is still on. onActionViewCollapsed() won't allow to search again and it hides the field without erasing the value in first search. In next searches it simply closes the keyboard. I included part of activity_main_actions.xml maybe it would help

Comment: In my case, setIconified(true); must be called twice sequentially before it actually collapsed.

Comment: Check the answer for similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46930606/1308990

Answer (score 49):

Use:

`searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();`

Instead of:

`searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();`

If you are using `AppCompat library`, then use:

`MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenuItem);`

Comment: Your answer did the trick, I am using a `toolbar` with `optionsMenu` search item.

Comment: I had the same situation as @blueware and this fixed my problem as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

In my case calling `invalidateOptionsMenu();` closes SearchView

Answer (score 4):

Solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072123/actionbar-search-will-not-close-after-search/27945135#27945135) is simple and works perfectly.

Basically, Call `setQuery("", false)` and `setIconified(true)` on `SearchView`.

Answer (score 3):

In menu_main.xml add :

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    />
```

and in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
final  MenuItem miSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) miSearch.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Searh For");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(newSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Toast.makeText(context,query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Here Put Your Code.
            //searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
            miSearch.collapseActionView();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a way to close the search bar programmatically. Unfortunately, there is not a method or an equivalent workaround for this. You may have already seen [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506230/how-do-i-close-a-searchview-programmatically) that had some suggestions, but no real way to do this.

Your first edit above that calls `setIconified(true)` is the best alternative. The docs suggest calling `setIconified(true)` should collapse the search widget, clear it, and remove it from focus if the attribute `iconifiedByDefault` is true (which it is by default so I don't see any problem with your activity_main_actions.xml).

Answer (score 1):

Hi i faced a similar scenario and so i think this changed to code should do the trick.
Hope this helps...:)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
Menu mMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_loc);  // take a reference with menue item
searchView = (SearchView) mMenuItem.getActionView(); //use that to find searchview
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchListener);

return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

SearchView.OnQueryTextListener searchListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    new JsoupGetData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q="+ query +    "&lang=pl").execute();
    try {
        mMenuItem.collapseActionView(); //this will collapse your search view
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return true;
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Activity:**

```
if (!searchView.isIconified())
        search.collapseActionView();
```

**Fragment:**

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (!searchView.isIconified())
        search.collapseActionView();
}
```